# How to properly manage id instance variable assign then retain

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id customDatePicker
```

Based upon user choice I will need a UIDatePicker or a UIPicker so I typecast the ivar and retain it and subsequently dealloc it. Is this the correct way to manage the property's memory?

```
// init snippet
if (useUIDatePicker) {
  customDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame] retain];
} else {
  customDatePicker = (UIPickerView *)[[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] retain];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [customDatePicker release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you declare the property as `assign`, you should not be retaining the object. The `assign` option is used for non-object variables and for situations where having a `retain`ed property would create a cycle, with both objects retaining each other. Declaring a property as `assign` means you will not be managing the memory of the object; you should neither call `retain` nor `release` on it.

You are also over-retaining the picker object. Retaining an object creates a claim on the object; you don't want it to disappear until you say you are done with it.  You relinquish a claim, allowing an object to be deleted, by calling `release`. When you call `alloc`, that creates the same kind of claim as calling `retain`. So this line:

```
[[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame] retain];
```

creates *two* claims, one for `alloc` and one for `retain`. Later, you only call `release` once, which means that you will always still have one claim on this object, and it will have turned into a memory leak.

What you should do is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id customDatePicker


if (useUIDatePicker) {
    customDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
} else {
    customDatePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
}
```

Now you have only one claim on the picker because you used `alloc`.

(You don't need to cast the assignment; when you are assign to a generic pointer you can use any kind of object.)

Also take a look at the Apple [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1) docs.

Comment: @Cory Also if you want to send retain and release to an object of type id at least make sure it conforms to the NSObject protocol by declaring it as `id<NSObject>`.

Comment: @Josh thanks for the answer.  I had a feeling I was going about it the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, then was is the difference between weak and assign ? I thought, that assign is for non object types and weak is work object types, but apparently they do the same thing ? Or weak sets the object to nil, when the retainCount is 0 and the assign doesn't do that ? So is assign like unsafe_unretained ?

Comment: This answer was written before the introduction of ARC, and thus before weak references, @denis631. Weak references under ARC are auto-nilling: you will either have a valid object or `nil`. Yes, an `assign` property is equivalent to an `__unsafe_unretained` pointer: if the object is deallocated, the property will have a dangling reference to an invalid object.

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell ! I since was surprised, when I looked at `UIAlertView.h` header file and the delegate wasn't declared as `weak`, but rather as `assign`, which made me really confused. Just why ? From Apple AlertView header : `@property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;    // weak reference`

Comment: [Why does Apple use assign rather than weak to store a delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20419317), @denis631.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thank you, Sir!