# Why does Apple use assign rather than weak to store a delegate?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, delegates, automatic-ref-counting, declared-property

Some Cocoa and Cocoa Touch classes declare their delegate properties as `assign` rather than `weak`, which forces users of the class to `nil` out the property in `dealloc`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.imageScrollView.delegate = nil;
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
}
```

Which is very cumbersome.

Why would Apple do it this way?

Comment: A **weak** reference is a reference to an object that does not stop it from being deallocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why is that not all system classes have been compiled with ARC.

> You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources
>   other than releasing instance variables. You do not have to (indeed
>   you cannot) release instance variables, but you may need to invoke
>   [systemClassInstance setDelegate:nil] on system classes and other code
>   that isn’t compiled using ARC.

See this page on developer.apple.com: [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: And after IOS 7 that hasn't changes?

Comment: Or at least Apple could say that assign means weak and unsafeassign means the old assign.

Comment: It's still the same in iOS 7.  You're right that it's not the most intuitive or convenient way for the delegates to be defined, as we use them in our programs.

Comment: So we got to set those delegate too nil

Comment: Exactly.  Set them to `nil` when in your delegate object's `dealloc` method to avoid potential crashes.